# Accidental overwrite of general register

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I am working on a homework assignment where we have to write comments to describe what some assembly code is doing. I am new to assembly so I can't really tell if the following code has a mistake.

I am using i686 architecture (not entirely sure what that means TBH)

This program determineGrade.s is being called by another program cs3843p3Driver.o

```
############################## determineGrade #####################
# Purpose:
#   determineGrade determines the grade of a student based on a
#   1000 pt scale.
# Parameters:
#   i 8(%ebp)  int iG1       Grade 1
#   i 12(%ebp) int iG2       Grade 2
#   i 16(%ebp) int iG3       Grade 3
#   i 20(%ebp) int iG4       Grade 4
#   i 24(%ebp) int iG5       Grade 5
#   i 28(%ebp) int iG6       Grade 6
#   i 32(%ebp) int iG7       Grade 7
#   i 36(%ebp) int iG8       Grade 8
#   i 40(%ebp) int iG9       Grade 9
#   i 44(%ebp) int iG10      Grade 10
# Locals:
#   -4(%ebp)  int iqTot
#   -8(%ebp)  int iTot
# Notes:
#   Grade is determined by
#       ??
# Return Value:
#   total grade on a 1000 pt scale
# Register Usage
#   %eax - mostly working register until after .L7 then ??
  .file "determineGrade.s"
  .text
.globl determineGrade
  .type determineGrade, @function
determineGrade:
  pushl %ebp
  movl  %esp, %ebp
    pushl %ebx                # Save the caller's %ebx since we are using %ebx
  subl  $20, %esp
  movl  $0, -4(%ebp)          # Overrides the caller's %ebx?
```

It looks as if the caller's `%ebx` value is stored in the same place as `iqTot`, which is defined as `-4(%ebp)`. Was the caller's `%ebx` value overwritten by accident?

Comment: Yeah that looks buggy.

Comment: i686 means 386 (32-bit code) with ISA extension up to and including Pentium Pro: e.g. `cmov` and `fcomi`

Comment: Probably they wanted to have the push after the sub for reserving the locals.

Answer (score 1):

I double checked with the professor, and yes, the stored value of `%ebx` was overwritten by `iqTot`. The function which calls `determineGrade` did not depend on `%ebx` to work properly, so the professor decided to leave the mistake to see if any of us would notice. Apparently I was the only student to call it out, so he gave me extra credit.

It should instead be:

- `iqTot` is stored at `-8(%ebp)`
- `iTot` is stored at `-12(%ebp)`

Comment: Haha, I love that it was intentional.  Yes, it's fairly common for callers to not actually depend on preserving registers; it can go either way.  Typically `main`'s caller is forgiving because it doesn't have much state, and `main` itself depends on compiler optimization.  32-bit PIC code historically always used EBX as a pointer to the GOT, so stepping on it almost always crashed your caller in a PIE executable.  But GCC these days can thunk EIP into any register and might not pick EBX.  (Still, 32-bit `-fPIE` / `-fPIC` is pretty inefficient because of no RIP-relative addressing.)